# to_d to always return 2 decimals places in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, decimal, currency

I'm dealing with currencies and I want to round down the number to 2 decimal places. Even if the number is 500.0, I would like it to be 500.00 to be consistent. When I do "500.00".to_d it converts it to 500.0.

Whats a good way of changing this behavior? I also use this method to round down to 2 digits and make sure it always has 2 decimals.

```
def self.round_down(x, n=2)
    s = x.to_s      
    l = s.index('.') ? s.index('.') + 1 + n : s.length
    s = s[0, l]
    s =  s.index('.') ? s.length - (s.index('.') + 1) == 1 ? s << '0' : s : s << '.00'      
    s.to_f
end
```

Answer (score 127):

In addition to mcfinnigan's answer, you can also use the following to get 2 decimal places

```
'%.2f' % 500 # "500.00"
```

This use case is known as the [string format operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25)

Comment: Caveat: this will round down or UP, eg. 500.016 becomes 500.02

Comment: yep expected behavior would be to follow the rules for rounding numbers

Answer (score 68):

Since you are using Rails and this seems to be related to a view, there's [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision):

```
number_with_precision(500, precision: 2)
#=> "500.00"

I18n.locale = :de
number_with_precision(500, precision: 2)
#=> "500,00"
```

For currencies I'd suggest [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency):

```
number_to_currency(500)
#=> "$500.00"
```

Comment: Just want to add that this answer covers a nil value, its great for `.erb` files.

Comment: For using the above solution you would want to add this

`include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`

Answer (score 37):

Here's a hint.  500.00 is a representation of the number 500.0

Specifically, sprintf will help you:

```
irb(main):004:0> sprintf "%.2f", 500.0
=> "500.00"
```

Comment: As the proverb goes, Real Programmers can write C in *any* language!  `'%.2f' % 500` is the Ruby idiom.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I blame it on far too many years of Java :/

Comment: sprintf is more explicit than % and I can easily get help about formatting parameters by pressing F1 on sprintf in my IDE

Comment: Caveat: this will round down or UP, eg. 500.016 becomes 500.02

Answer (score 13):

Do not use floating point numbers to represent money. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) for a good overview of why this is a bad idea.

Instead, store monetary values as integers (representing cents), or have a look at the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem that provides lots of useful functionality for dealing with such values.

Answer (score 2):

**There was a requirement to round DOWN.**

*Most other answers round 500.016 UP to 500.02*

**Try:**

```
def self.round_down(x, n = 2)
  "%.#{n}f" % x.to_d.truncate(n)
end

irb(main):024:0> x=500.0; '%.2f' % x.to_d.truncate(2)
=> "500.00"
irb(main):025:0> x=500.016; '%.2f' % x.to_d.truncate(2)
=> "500.01"
```