# Displaying an output in Ruby to 2 decimal places

Tags: ruby

I want to display a price such that if the answer is 10.1 the ouput would be 10.10 and if the answer is 20, the output would be 20.00

I have gone through the forums and used so many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900537/to-d-to-always-return-2-decimals-places-in-ruby) but it still hasn't worked for me. The answer is for rails but I am working on Ruby.`s=  '%2f' % @price` and the output I get is `12.100000`

Comment: You copied the example incorrectly. Should be `'%.2f'`, not `'%2f'`

Comment: Also, instead of scouring the internet indefinitely for a working snippet, you could have just read the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a dot in the format to say you want the `2` to be the precision after the decimal dot:

```
s = '%.2f' % @price
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the round method, so:

```
12.100000.round(2) => 12.10
```