# ruby round off to two decimal place and keep zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding

i want to round off a number upto two decimal place in ruby such that

`(0.02 * 270187).round(2)` is 5403.74  which is correct

but

`(0.02 * 278290).round(2)` is 5565.8 which is not consistent with previous one

i want to make it look like 5565.80

Please tell me how can i do it in ruby

Comment: [The answer to your question is found here, thanks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900537/to-d-to-always-return-2-decimals-places-in-ruby)

Answer (score 12):

This will do the trick:

```
> sprintf("%.2f",(0.02 * 270187))
#=> "5403.74" 
> sprintf("%.2f",(0.02 * 278290))
#=> "5565.80"
> sprintf("%.2f",(0.02 * 270187)).to_f > 100  # If you plan to Compare something with result
#=> true
```

**OR**

```
> '%.2f' % (0.02 * 270187)
#=> "5403.74"
> '%.2f' % (0.02 * 278290)
#=> "5565.80"
```

### [Demo](https://repl.it/B16w)

**Note:**   The result is always a string, but since you're rounding I assume you're doing it for presentation purposes anyway. **[sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)** can format any number almost any way you like. If you are planning to compare anything with this result then convert this string to float by adding `.to_f` at the end. **[Like this](https://repl.it/B16w/1)**

Comment: i am getting this error ArgumentError (comparison of String with 0 failed):

Comment: @user4965201 : as I already said it will return as string. and you are trying to compare something with this result further

Comment: @user4965201 : If you wanted to compare then add `.to_f` at the end. [check](https://repl.it/B16w/1)

Comment: i have done this cost =  ('%.2f' % (to_mb(monthly_usage) * cost_per_mb)).to_f
but i got a record like 5565.8 , no zero at the end

Comment: what is value of `monthly_usage` and `cost_per_mb` and what is `to_mb(monthly_usage)`

Comment: do it like  `('%.2f' % ((to_mb(monthly_usage) * cost_per_mb)).to_f )`

Comment: @user4965201 `('%.2f' % ( 0.02 * 278290).to_f)` this will return `"5565.80"`

Comment: but i want it as 5565.80 when i do "5565.80".to_f it gives 5565.8

Comment: `to_f` will remove last zero after `.` so if it is `1.20` become `1.2` and `1.23` will remain same.

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

number_with_precision(value, :precision => 2) # value.to_f if you have string
```

or like this

```
'%.2f' % your_value
```

Hope it helps!
Further you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900537/to-d-to-always-return-2-decimals-places-in-ruby)

Comment: i am getting ArgumentError (comparison of String with 0 failed) ... i am using this method in rails

Comment: You can convert your string to float like `value.to_f`

Comment: i am getting some value as 0, think thats why i am getting the error

Comment: Can you please provide your code, where you are actually using it.

Comment: cost = number_with_precision((to_mb(monthly_usage) * cost_per_mb).to_f, :precision => 2)

Comment: getting this error ArgumentError (comparison of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer with 0 failed):

Comment: I am assuming, you are getting correct values from `to_mb(monthly_usage)` and `cost_per_mb`. 
Also have you included `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` ? 

Can you please also try with `'%.2f' % (to_mb(monthly_usage) * cost_per_mb)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95552/discussion-between-user4965201-and-dusht).

Comment: @user4965201 You can do `cost = ('%.2f' % (to_mb(monthly_usage) * cost_per_mb)).to_f`