# How do I display 2 decimals when there is a trailing 0 in a float

Tags: ruby, rounding

How can I display 2 decimal places (padding) on a float even if the trailing number is a 0. So, if I sum only the :cost values in the example below I would like it to return 23.00

```ruby
items = [
    {customer: "John", item: "Soup", cost:("%.2f"% 8.50)}, 
    {customer: "Sarah", item: "Pasta", cost:("%.2f"% 12.00)}, 
    {customer: "John", item: "Coke", cost:("%.2f" % 2.50)}
]
```

PROBLEM: 
I have success displaying cost: values with two decimal places. However, the result returns a "string". I have tried ***("%.2f" % 2.50).to_f*** with no such luck. I need a float so that I can complete the following inject code.

```
totalcost = items.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:cost]}

puts totalcost
```

When running this to sum the total cost I receive the following error because I cannot convert the string to a float successfully. **String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)**

Comment: See [ruby round off to two decimal place and keep zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802099/ruby-round-off-to-two-decimal-place-and-keep-zero)

Comment: You shouldn't use floats for monetary values.

Comment: @Stefan why not? If we collect all the small inaccuracies in floating point math as currency we could be rich :)

Comment: @stefan thank you for the insight. I have now covered that topic and will not be using float to reflect monetary value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of cost values after converting it to number(Integer/Float).

```
totalcost  = items.map { |x| x[:cost].to_f }.sum
```

The value of `totalcost` can be formatted with [sprintf method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) in whatever way we want to display.

```
sprintf("%.2f", totalcost)
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This one did the trick!! Thank you for the help. I'm just starting out in this programming path and I was able to burn this off my backlog

Answer (score 0):

hash[:cost] is still returns a String. you could just cover it to a float before adding it to sum

```
totalcost = items.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:cost].to_f}
```

Comment: unfortunately this still returns the total cost as 23.0 and not 23.00 as I wanted. Thank you for your reply however